# Fetching 1 row at a time

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

How do I fetch 1 row at a time? Here is what I have right now (http://prntscr.com/i4vqjs).

I want each username to have its own box.

My current code is.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM points ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['playername'] . "<br>"; 
}
}
```

What changes would I need to make to my script to make this possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: change the LIMIT

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "fetch one row at a time"? Your SQL query should return only one result or the PHP code should iterate through one result at a time? Also, I prefer the object oriented style for PHP database connections, as it lets you keep track of connection easier.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I don't want to change the limit because I want to place the other data  for the boxes below

Comment: use pagination then or html table. Unsure what you want here exactly, given the screenshot

Comment: u want to print each username in separate boxes right? echo each row in each div

Comment: @AnandhuNadesh yes :)

Comment: your screenshot does not support the code you posted, so where are those divs?

Comment: where is the code for those boxes?

Answer (score 0):

You must have the box design HTML for view. Try to put the box HTML inside loop. I am adding simple `<div>` in place of which you will add you box html.

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    echo '<div class="username-box">'.$row['playername'].'</div>'; 
}
```

Where i have mentioned class `username-box` design that class by css or use your own design.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey, I did this & it kind of worked, however all of the boxes are stack ontop of each other & I don't know how to seperate them. I tried to edit margin-bottom but no luck. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to also render boxes inside your `while` loop.
Example

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<div class="box">' . $row['playername'] . "</div>"; 
}
```

Comment: Hey, I did this & it kind of worked, however all of the boxes are stack ontop of each other & I don't know how to seperate them. I tried to edit margin-bottom but no luck. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, if you tried my solution, then make sure you have in your CSS code similar to this
`.box{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}`